# Accessing all objects created from ClientFactory in Twisted?

Tags: python, events, twisted, reactor

I'm working on a basic Twisted application to help me learn how reactors work with multiple services.  The basic outline of what I'd like my script to do is as follows:

> My script will be both a Web Server and an IRC Client.  Every time a request is made to the web server, the script should say a message on IRC.

I've got an IRC client working, and a twisted.web server working, and can have them run simultaneously in one script.  The problem occurs when I try to make them interact with one another.  Here's how I initiate the server/client:

```
import sys
from twisted.words.protocols import irc
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

# Define my custom IRC Client, ClientFactory, and Web Application

chan = sys.argv[1]
site = server.Site(Home())
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.connectTCP('irc.freenote.net', 6667, IRCBotFactory(chan))
reactor.run()
```

Using the code above, the two parts of my client run simultaneously without issue.  When trying to make the IRC Client send messages to the server upon HTTP request, however, I realized that I don't actually have reference to an IRCBot intance, as I initiated the reactor with the IRCBotFactory and let Twisted handle initialization of the actual bot object.

Is there a way to get all child instances of a factory in Twisted, or is there another way for me to initiate the IRC Client (perhaps bypassing the Factory and simply using an IRCBot instance)?

Comment: when you say 'send messages', do you mean it would be sufficient to connect to the webserver instance, or do you need access to the actual server object?  if just the former, can't you connect to it over localhost via your client?

Comment: When a browser connects to my HTTP server, the server needs to tell all of my IRC Clients to send messages to the IRC server they are currently connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Twisted [FAQ entries](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother) entries discusses a problem like this one.  Just remember that a Site is a factory and it should be easy to apply a similar solution to your case.